# Image fixed on hover

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

When  hovering the image ,image moves to the left,I want it to stay at the new position where it moved to, while moving the pointer away.

Thanks in advance

```css
.object{
  position:absolute;
}
.bird{
    top: 50%;
    left: 64%;
}
#twit:hover .move{
    transform: translate(-350px,0) rotate(-360deg);
  transition:all 2s linear;
    
}
```

```html
<div id="twit">
  <div class="object bird move">
    <img  width="50px" height="50px" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ0rasMS9P_knjCI0jPS2S3EavRVR57YSoOJSomU3tcmaxV_zom5cZWOg">
    <b>Welcome Home</b>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you really mean by this? can you just elaborate?

Comment: When I hover the image ,image moves to the left,I want it to stay at the new position where it moved to(it has to stay in the left), when i move the pointer away.I am new to this concept ,help me out.

Comment: With the :hover psuedo, once you move the cursor away it will fall back to its original position, it's not possible for it to "stick" there with just css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want can be achieve, but you need to remove your `:hover selector` and use that as `css animation`. Another way is using `jQuery mouseenter event`.

Using **CSS animation** and removing `hover selector`.

```css
.object{
  position:absolute;
}
.bird{
    top: 50%;
    left: 64%;
}
.move{
    -webkit-animation:mv 2s;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes mv{
from{
    transform: translate(0,0) rotate(0deg);
  }
to{
    transform: translate(-350px,0) rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="twit">
  <div class="object bird move">
    <img  width="50px" height="50px" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ0rasMS9P_knjCI0jPS2S3EavRVR57YSoOJSomU3tcmaxV_zom5cZWOg">
    <b>Welcome Home</b>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another way is using **jQuery mouseenter event**, which performs same `css animation`, but stop your element at new position.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("#twit").on("mouseenter",function(){
    $("#twit > .object").addClass("nwmv");
    });
});
```

```css
.object{
  position:absolute;
}
.bird{
    top: 50%;
    left: 64%;
}
.nwmv{
    -webkit-animation:mvv 2s;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes mvv{
from{
    transform: translate(0,0) rotate(0deg);
  }
to{
    transform: translate(-350px,0) rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="twit">
  <div class="object bird move">
    <img  width="50px" height="50px" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ0rasMS9P_knjCI0jPS2S3EavRVR57YSoOJSomU3tcmaxV_zom5cZWOg">
    <b>Welcome Home</b>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Using Javascript,**

```js
var b = document.getElementById("twit");
b.onmouseenter = function mv(){
var a = document.querySelector(".move");
a.style.transition = "2s ease";
a.style.transform = "translate(-350px,0) rotate(-360deg)";
}
```

```css
.object{
  position:absolute;
}
.bird{
    top: 50%;
    left: 64%;
}
```

```html
<div id="twit">
  <div class="object bird move">
    <img  width="50px" height="50px" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ0rasMS9P_knjCI0jPS2S3EavRVR57YSoOJSomU3tcmaxV_zom5cZWOg">
    <b>Welcome Home</b>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This Is What I was expecting , can I do this in javascript ,not in jquery

Comment: @Gowtham check updated codes using Javascript. That's just not possible using hover selector.

Comment: Sure @frnt :-) ;-)